# How to setup magento cron job and init action of the controller?

Tags: magento, controller, action, cron

As above, is there a way to do it? How can I define it in config.xml of my custom module?

Comment: Magento cronjobs can obviously be set up. What do you mean by an init action of a controller? You need to be clearer about what you are trying to do.

Comment: By default in magento when you configure cronjob in config.xml you add <run><model>mymodule/modelName::modelMethod</model></run> But function I need to run is in controller. Is it possible to run this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have ever seen, you cannot directly run controller actions in a cronjob, since that is not a terribly sensible thing to do outside of a user context. The easiest thing to do here is to put that functionality you need into a model and call that from the cronjob.

More information on the controller action you want to fire would be helpful in giving further advice.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Yes there is no possibility to do that. I've done it just like you said and it works, Thank you

Comment: @joseph Can you please guide me for this scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189082/send-emails-with-pdf-attachment-in-magento-cronjob